# Как открывать файл в Python в определенной программе?

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell

Здраствуйте! Я хочу написать программу, которая будет исполнять файл wc.ps1 в PowerShell, но вместо того чтобы открывать файл в PSHELL она открывает в Notepad.
Как это исправить? Буду рад ответу. Код:

`import tepp
 #Моя библиотека
 #Выполнение файлов
 tepp.exe("wc.ps1")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделал `hello_world.ps1`:

```
$strString = "Hello World"
write-host $strString
[Environment]::Exit(0)
```

Есть разные способы запуска других приложений и я приведу часть из них.

Самый простой это `os.system`, если же нужно больше контроля над запущенным приложением, тогда использовать `subprocess`:

```
import os
WIN_DIR = os.path.expandvars('%WINDIR%')
FILE_NAME_POWERSHELL = os.path.join(WIN_DIR, r'system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe')

file_name_ps1 = 'hello_world.ps1'
command = FILE_NAME_POWERSHELL + ' -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ' + file_name_ps1

print('OS:')
os.system(command)
```

Консоль:

```
OS:
Hello World
```

---

Используя `subprocess`:

```
print()
print('subprocess.call:')

import subprocess
retcode = subprocess.call(command, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
print(retcode)

print()
print('subprocess.check_output:')
output = subprocess.check_output(command, universal_newlines=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
print(output)

print()
print('subprocess.run:')
rs = subprocess.run(command)
print(rs.returncode)

print()
print('subprocess.Popen:')
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
rs = Popen(command, universal_newlines=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
for line in rs.stdout:
    line = line.rstrip()
    print(line)
```

Консоль:

```
subprocess.call:
Hello World
0

subprocess.check_output:
Hello World

subprocess.run:
Hello World
0

subprocess.Popen:
Hello World
```

---

Больше информации о модуле `subprocess` можно найти в: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html. Там полно примеров

Comment: gil9red, функция `tepp.exe("")` исполняет роль `os.system`. :-)

Comment: @KostyaDenysov, ну я то откуда знал? :) Тогда вам достаточно передавать `command`

Comment: Вот только не надо хардкодить C:\WINDOWS\! Винда может быть и по другому пути быть установлена...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, допилил ;)